# Is it possible to longClick on a WebView to return the position where I clicked?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, position, onlongclicklistener

I want to get the exact X and Y position where I longClicked in the window, but I found there's no method in OnLongClickListener to do this.

Is this possible?

Or I have to listen by JavaScript in the webView? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement the method

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
```

in your view and then you can see the
coordinates of touching point calling the function event.getX() and
event.getY() Then get this to set a couple variables that the onLongClick method can access.
More info can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)

Answer (score 0):

The complete working code looks like this. You need to overwrite onTouchEvent, indeed...

```
public class SubWebView extends WebView {
    private Point lastTouch;

    public SubWebView (Context context) {
        super(context);
        ...
        super.setLongClickable(true);
        setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                    return handler.onLongClick(lastTouch.x, lastTouch.y);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev)    {
        lastTouch = new Point((int) ev.getX(), (int) ev.getY()) ;
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
```

Especially, for some reason, it does not work setting an OnTouchEventListener to capture the coordinate - I'd maybe like to know why.